# Update html table populated by SQL can't do simple page refresh because a timer needs to run

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I can not do simple page refresh because there is a stop watch running that can't be refreshed.
When the timer starts the page needs to stop refreshing. It can be refreshed before.
I need the table shown below to update!

I have tried isset on the start button.
I have tried getting the stop watch time with javascript

please dont talk to me about security or deprecation that will come later.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT runner,gamenum, gamename FROM runs");

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{

if(strcmp($row2['gamename'], $game )==0){
$t++;
    echo "<TR><TD><FONT COLOR='WHITE' SIZE='2' FACE='ARIAL'>".$row2['runner']."   </td><TD><div align=right><FONT COLOR=".$color."face=arial size=2></div></td></tr>";
 }
```

Comment: <font> is deprecated, mysql_* also. If you develop new code, make sure you follow the current standards.

Comment: Please explain your question better and put more code. what do you mean by stopwatch? where is the code you entered located?

Comment: <SCRIPT><!--output=textbox where timer value is.-->
var yup=setInterval(reloader(), 6000);
function reloader(){
xy=document.getElementById("output").value;
if(xy=="0.0.0")
{
document.write("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'/>");
}
else
{
document.write("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='999999'/>");
clearInterval(yup);
}

}


</SCRIPT>

Answer (score 0):

any update you want to do with PHP is going to require a refresh of the page unless you use ajax to swap the html for your table out with updated data.